# Creating a portfolio website with backend UI

Tags: backend

I'm working on a portfolio website for a client. He requested to have a gallery 
section where the thumbnails leads to the details page with all the information about the work .
[image]

He wants to have an back-end UI where he can login Upload new thumbnails and Their respective Details page.

**Question**

How can I build a back-end UI for such a case where he can easily upload pictures and select type of layout for the description page he wants and also some pictures in there to make it feel good .

Are there any already available Open Source Tools or Frameworks ?

Thanks a lot.

Cheers,

PS:He finds Wix a little work heavy. Wants an easier and faster way to do things
I'm using nodejs for designing the site

Answer (score 2):

"He wants to have an back-end UI where he can login Upload new thumbnails and Their respective Details page."

You can use `cms` like `wordpress` to easily achieve this, with using `Advanced custom fields` plugin.

"Are there any already available Open Source Tools or Frameworks ? "

`wordpress` is Free and open source